# How do i keep my buttons in the same position on browser resize

Tags: html, css

I am adding two buttons to my web page. The problem is that when I resize my browser window the buttons get out of place and sometimes get on top of eachother depending on how I resize the window. I've searched and discovered that if I used `position : absolute` on the CSS it would solve the problem but it doens't solve in my code and I would like to know how can I avoid this problem.

The HTML that I have is this one :

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden; /*  Disable scrollbars */
    display: block;  /* No floating content on sides */
}

.button-a,.button-b {
  padding: 0.6em 2em;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: rgb(209, 192, 192);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
}

.button-a:before,.button-b:before {
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    #ff0000,
    #ff7300,
    #fffb00,
    #48ff00,
    #00ffd5,
    #002bff,
    #7a00ff,
    #ff00c8,
    #ff0000
  );
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  background-size: 400%;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  width: calc(100% + 4px);
  height: calc(100% + 4px);
  animation: glowing-button-color 20s linear infinite;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes glowing-button-color {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 400% 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}

.button-a:after,.button-b:after {
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.button-a {
    top:1%;
    left:94%;
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    position: absolute;
    background: none; 
    
}


.button-b {
    
    top:5.9%;
    left:94%;
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    position: absolute;
    background: none; 

}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button-a" id="button_a">A</button>
<button type="button" class="button-b" id="button_b">B</button>
```

I am new to CSS so I don't know much about it and don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: see "responsive web design". You never want to use absolute positioning due to cell phones - when you focus in a textbox or text area a soft keyboard overtakes half the viewport. Basically, you need to assume that the screen size, or viewport size, will change and design your UI to play nice. At a minimum design for a phone view and a desktop view. Good luck and keep coding!

Answer (score 0):

I will asume your HTML is just a blank template with 2 buttons in it, just like you display it in your question.

First of all, remove the `position: absolute` from your buttons. You only want `position: absolute` to your pseudo-classes ( ::before ) if you really want to work with pseudo-classes. Replace `position: absolute` with `position: relative` on the button elements.

If you want to make your buttons to stay IN place ( as if they are pinned ) you just have to add to your code

```
.button-a {
  inset: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.button-b {
  inset: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

Now, what this will do is simple. First keep in mind the `inset` is just as writing top: __, left: __, bottom: __ and right: __. This will tell the browser to render your buttons at a specific point relative to the parent element ( in this case your body - I assume ).

So the above code block can also be written like:

```
.button-a {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.button-b {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

Setting, for example, a top value equal to 20px this translates to 20px bellow the top 'line' of your parent container the browser will place your element, in this case your button.

Just set a diferent `inset` for each button and I think you are good to go.